# How to run Flutter app on multiple iOS simulators at the same time?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I tried running `flutter run -d all`, but I always get these errors:

```
s
    NULL
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    error: Build service could not start build operation: unknown error while handling message: Could not acquire
```

This command works if I try running both Android emulator and iOS simulator, but never for two or more iOS simulators at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a known [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50455) in the Flutter SDK where  it uses Xcode's latest build system, which prohibits the concurrent builds to run with a single `flutter run` command.

If you want to test your app against multiple devices at the same time, run the following:

- `flutter devices`
- `flutter run -d <device_id_iphone>` && `flutter run -d <device_id_ipad>`

The catch for this workaround is you have two isolated Flutter app instances running.

If you're running them on the command line, you have to reload each instance individually.